# How to convert String data to int data for preparing linear regression?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to prepare my data to regression. So I am trying to convert String column to integer with this code :

```
train["comment"] = train["comment"].astype(int)
```

But I am  getting this error :

> runfile('C:/Users/hayyi/.spyder-py3/temp.py',
> wdir='C:/Users/hayyi/.spyder-py3') Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\hayyi.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 57, in 
> train["comment"] = train["comment"].astype(int)
>
> File
> "D:\SpyderUI\MiniConda\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
> line 5815, in astype
> new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
>
> File
> "D:\SpyderUI\MiniConda\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py",
> line 418, in astype
> return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
>
> File
> "D:\SpyderUI\MiniConda\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py",
> line 327, in apply
> applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
>
> File
> "D:\SpyderUI\MiniConda\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py",
> line 591, in astype
> new_values = astype_array_safe(values, dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
>
> File
> "D:\SpyderUI\MiniConda\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py",
> line 1309, in astype_array_safe
> new_values = astype_array(values, dtype, copy=copy)
>
> File
> "D:\SpyderUI\MiniConda\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py",
> line 1257, in astype_array
> values = astype_nansafe(values, dtype, copy=copy)
>
> File
> "D:\SpyderUI\MiniConda\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py",
> line 1174, in astype_nansafe
> return lib.astype_intsafe(arr, dtype)
>
> File "pandas_libs\lib.pyx", line 679, in
> pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "He got his
> money... now he lies in wait till after the election in 2 yrs....
> dirty politicians need to be afraid of Tar and feathers again... but
> they aren't and so the people get screwed."

By the way, I try this to but I am getting same error :

```
train["comment"]=train["comment].str.replace(',','').astype(int)
```

And another question, that kind of converting is right way to prepare string data to regression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the string values are numbers with data type string, try:

```
train['comment']= pd.to_numeric(train['comment'], errors='coerce')
```

If the column contains any NaN values, use this:

```
train['comment']= pd.to_numeric(train['comment'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(np.int64)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. That solved my problem. Now I am getting "Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')." error while trying to regression. Can you tell me why i am getting this ?

Comment: Sure, let me give a fix for that.

Comment: Check the updated answer